# Select PK from duplicated values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, having

In a table i have 4 columns, `ID` and `V1`, `V2` and `V3`. How can i select the ID of the rows where Value1 and Value2 repeat? ex:

```
ID | V1 | V2 | V3  
1    A    B    X
2    A    C    Y
3    A    B    Z  
4    A    B    W
5    F    B    K
6    A    B    N
7    H    B    N
8    O    C    N
```

I expect as result: 1,3,4 and 6

What i have already try

```
select MovimentacaoContaId from MovimentacaoConta
group by NumeroDocumento,PessoaId,DataEmissaoReal,ValorTotalReal
having count(NumeroDocumento)>1 and count(PessoaId)>1 and count(DataEmissaoReal)>1 and count(ValorTotalReal)>1

select MovimentacaoContaId from MovimentacaoConta
group by NumeroDocumento,PessoaId,DataEmissaoReal,ValorTotalReal
having count(NumeroDocumento,PessoaId,DataEmissaoReal,ValorTotalReal)>1 //obvious error...

select distinct MovimentacaoContaId from MovimentacaoConta
group by NumeroDocumento,PessoaId,DataEmissaoReal,ValorTotalReal
having count(NumeroDocumento)>1 and count(PessoaId)>1 and count(DataEmissaoReal)>1 and count(ValorTotalReal)>1
```

PS: i want these specific columns because V1 and V2 should be a compisite PK, but previous developer did not make it so and on top of it inserted a couple of bugs that instead of updating a record, inserted...

Comment: Show us **your own effort** first! We'll be glad to help - but SO isn't just a "gimme ze codez" service ..... also, from your description and that sample data, it's really not quite clear what you're trying to do. **WHY** do you want to get 1, 3, 4 and 6? Why not 2? Why not 5 ? Please explain in more detail

Comment: it's a emergency that i just got thrown into... i'm editing to add where i've been...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to self-join in some way because you have to relate an aggregate to each row.

```
SELECT
    ID
FROM
    MovimentacaoConta mc
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        V1,
        V2,
        COUNT(*) AS row_count
    FROM
        MovimentacaoConta
    GROUP BY
        V1,
        V2
) mc0
ON
    mc.v1 = mc0.v1
AND
    mc.v2 = mc0.v2
WHERE
    mc0.row_count > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select table.* 
  from table 
  join (select V1, V2 
          from table
         group by V1, V2 
        having count(*) > 1) V1V2
    on table.V1 = V1V2.V1 
   and table.V2 = V1V2.V2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my favorite way of doing that:

```
;with cte as 
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by v1,v2 order by v1,v2) as rn, *
    from your_tbl
)
select * from cte where rn > 1
```